# IP route of many subnets - one rule

Tags: linux, routing, ip, routes

I want to simply modify routing rule in Linux.
Now I have to add:

> ip route add 5.3.4.3 via 10.4.4.4
>
> ip route add 3.4.5.3 via 10.4.4.4
>
> ip route add 200.45.32.3 via 10.4.4.4
>
> ip route add 9.33.4.3 via 10.4.4.4

Does exist someting like ipset for ip route? I want to have this IP addresses in one list 5.3.4.3, 3.4.5.3, 200.45.32.3 and 9.33.4.3. I want to have only one route insted of 4(or more).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need 4 rules if you want to set the route for 4 different single IP.

Bu you could do a little script if you don't want to have to repeat the commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
GW=10.4.4.4
for ip in 5.3.4.3 3.4.5.3 200.45.32.3 9.33.4.3
do
  ip route add -host $ip gw $GW
done
```